# filling a matrix with equations results in c++

Tags: c++

I need to make a matrix `[2][25]` and fill it with two equations: the first line with `x=500/l` and the second line with `y=500/col`, `l = 5`, `col=5`, so we will have like 5 results, but I need them to be repetitive like this

```
x: 100 100 100 100 100 125 125 125 125 125  166 166 166 166 166 250 250 250 250 250 500 500 500 500 500

y: 100 125 166 250 500  100 125 166 250 500 100 125 166 250 500 100 125 166 250 500 100 125 166 250 500
```

they are coordinates of points in a zone of (500,500)
here is the code that I made please correct me or tell me what to change!

```
#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc , char** argv)
{
int t[2][25];
int x;
int y;
for (int l = 5; l > 0; --l)
{
    for ( int col = 5 ; col > 1; --col)
    {
        t[0][x]= 500 / l;
        t[1][y]= 500 / col;
    }
    std::cout << t[0][x] << '\t' ;
    std::cout << t[1]y] << '\t' ;
    std::cout<<'\n';
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` and `y` are not initialized.

Comment: No, I think you'll find Harry is right on that point.

Comment: @MrSofiane Please show, on which line, they are initialized, then.

Comment: @paxdiablo so initializing them inside the for, i initialized them at the beginning, so then what do you suggest to do after ?

Comment: @paxdiablo line 6, i initialized them at the beginning not inside the for loop, help then .

Comment: @MrSofiane Neither `x`, nor `y` value is even changed, anywhere in your code example. Perhaps you are looking at a different code example, than you are showing us? You are initializing `l`, and `col` values. Never `x`, or `y`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius thats why i'm asking for help not to get a down vote

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius how do i do that plesae ?

Comment: @MrSofiane 1) So, the one problem was already pointed out: you are not initializing `x`, and `y`, but you are using them. That's undefined behavior. You, for some reason, seem to not accept this fact. 2) "line 6" starting count from which point? If I start from the top, it's `int x;` line, which, definitely, doesn't include initialization.

Comment: @MrSofiane "_how do i do that plesae ?_" How do you do what? Initialize? You did that with `l`, or `col`, so you already know how to do that.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius no no i am accepting that, i meant okey i initialize it inside for int x =0, then what should i do next ? i really need help buddy

Comment: MrSofiane, your code does *not* have the text `for  (int x = 0` anywhere, I suspect you're looking at different code.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes i know, i don't understand english very good its my 3rd language, i didnt understand " initialize" i thought initializing is just puting int x int y, i did it and added x++, y++ and my code worked fine thank you for your time you're a nice person unlike someone thank you !

Comment: No problems, MrSofiane, glad I could help. Just to be clear, `int x;` is a declaration, declaring that something exists without giving it an explicit value (though there are some situations in which it will get an *implicit* value, but this code is not one of them). Initialisation is `int x = 42;`, where you're both declaring *and* initialising.

Comment: @paxdiablo thank you for your advices you're a nice guy ! i will not make the same mistakes again thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print the x and y variables at first and then increase them.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int t[2][25];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int l = 5; l > 0; l--)
    {
        for (int col = 5; col >=1; col--)
        {
            t[0][x] = 500 / l;
            t[1][y] = 500 / col;
    
            std::cout << t[0][x] << '\t';
            std::cout << t[1][y] << '\t';
            std::cout << '\n';
            x++;
            y++;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type "int x;" and compile the program, all the compiler will do is allocate memory and label it with the name "x" for you to use in the scope it was declared. It is called declaring a variable. Now if this "x" was never assigned a value and you attempt to use this variable, the program will act in an unexpected way (undefined behavior). What you need to do is assign a value to your variable and your problem will go away. This is initializing the variable.

Looking at your code, you have to correct other mistakes in your program in order to make it work the way you want it to. Also, read up on some beginner C++ before you go and search answers for your homework on forums.

Comment: i did not search answers for my homework, i just needed help, of course i read some documentation, i didn't know i had to assigne value to x, my code works, look at the first answer he just added x++ y++ and it worked as i wanted, so yeah thank you for your comments